# Ansible end role when one host is ok

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

Ansible: 2.9.9

Hi Again,

I search the method to execute a task from playbook in one of three hosts.

#### Inventory file:

```
[servers]
server01
server02
server03
```

#### Playbook file:

This code execute ping role equal times of elements in group "servers".

```
- hosts: servers
  roles:
    - roles:
      - ping
```

I search the method of the role is ended when one of the elements from "servers" group as "ok".

I desire to do this with "jinja filter", it is possible?

Example: If the server01 is ok, don't lauch in others host. But if server01 is not ok continue to send to others hosts.

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would expect that *meta: end_play* and "serial: 1" could help, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - block:
        - ping:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} OK."
        - meta: end_play
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} failed."
```

The module *meta: end_play* should terminate the play if a host successfully completes *ping*. Unfortunately, this does not work. There is an [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73971) open. The play completes all reachable hosts

<sup>(abridged)</sup>

```yaml
  msg: server1 OK.
  msg: server2 OK.
  msg: server3 OK.
```

Please comment here when the [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73971) is resolved.

Comment: You know all! I start to follow the url of issue. thank's